# raw_input not working on linux with unexpected token

Tags: python, python-2.7

raw_input not working here is the error

```
./runyrun.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./runyrun.py: line 1: `name = raw_input("What is your name? ")'
```

operating system: linux

One last thing if it matters:
It doesnt work before i run this command to the file:

```
chmod +x runyrun.py
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like a Python stack trace. Are you sure that you're running your program using Python? Because I think you might be using Bash.

Comment: Your code is not being run with Python. What's the first line of the file, is there a `#!/bin/env python` shebang line?

Comment: @Kevin @Martijn Pieters Im such an idiot I used `./runyrun.py` to run the command I should of used `python runyrun.py` Thanks for helping me and have a nice day!

Comment: @R.Randi, if `./runyrun.py` gave that error, that means the script didn't have a proper shebang; if it started with `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line, then `python` would be invoked to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is not getting run by python. Either run your program as `python runyrun.py` or make sure your code has a valid hash bang (something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`) as your first line and run it as `./runyrun.py`